# How to change text of a button when another button is pressed in a different view

Tags: iphone, ios8, xcode6.3

In my project I am trying to count the number of rows selected and then when I press the button it goes to the previous view and the button text in that view should change to how many rows are selected. I realize I must be making a simple mistake, but can't figure it out. I would appreciate some help with this.

Here is the code I am using in the .m file:

```
- (IBAction)doneButton:(id)sender
{
    appDelegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    CountryModel *countryModel = [[CountryModel alloc]init];

    CompareViewController *compareViewController = [[CompareViewController alloc]init];

        [compareViewController. addCountries setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Countries Selected", countId] forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"%ld",countId);
//    compareViewController.addCountries.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Countries Selected", countId];
    compareViewController.Cid = countryModel.Id;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:compareViewController animated:YES];
}
```

And here is the .h code for CompareViewController:

```
@interface CompareViewController : UIViewController

@property (assign) NSInteger Cid;
- (IBAction)addRemoveCountries:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *addCountries;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form you code I see is you are setting the title even before the view is initialised. What you should do is add a property to your `CompareViewController` set it on the action. and in `viewDidLoad:` method of `CompareViewController` set this title to your button.

**EDIT:**

In your CompareViewController.h add a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *buttonTitleyouNeedToSet;
```

In `doneButton:` add following ling after you initialise `compareViewController`

```
compareViewController.buttonTitleyouNeedToSet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld Countries Selected", countId];
```

In CompareViewController.m in `viewDidLoad:` set the button title:

```
[addCountries setTitle:buttonTitleyouNeedToSet forState:(UIControlState)UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Then how can I pass the value of countId to CompareViewController? It is defined in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;

    NSArray *arr = appDelegate.navController.viewControllers;

    for (UIViewController *vc in arr) {
        if (vc isKindOfClass:[CompareViewController class]) {
            CompareViewController *cvc = (CompareViewController *)vc;
            [cvc.btn setTitle:@"Hello" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            break;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will helpful